# Is mysqlcheck enough for a consistency check equivalent to SQL Server's DBCC CHECKDB?

Tags: mysql

I am running the following command from a batch file, it is working well. I want to understand if it is enough for the consistency check like what we do in SQL Server `dbcc checkdb` with `all_errormsgs`, `no_infomsgs`.

Do I need to add any other option to `mysqlcheck` or use a different command?

```shell
mysqlcheck --check  -u root --password=somepassword --port=port_no \
 --all-databases >"E:\MYSQL_Backup\DBCC\mysqlcheck_log.txt"
```

Comment: Which ENGINE are your tables using?  What "consistency" issues have you seen?  (InnoDB takes care of itself and should never need a tool like this.)

Comment: Please give us extra info.

Comment: It is a new database, no issues so far. All are in InnoDB engine, as per your statement, InnoDB does not require consistency check right?

Comment: Can anyone confirm pls?